# Error in sql query Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I newbie in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. I have a SQL query, which shows a time that had been spendeed on solving each request by every employee. Data base is Microsoft SQL Server on Windows Server 2008.

I want to find a number of requests that had been solved in a 6 hours and below in percentage terms and also a sum of all solved requests of every employee

below and above 6 hours.

This is my SQL query but while it works it produces an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '>' Incorrect syntax near 'tmp_table.'

SQL Query:

```
SELECT id, fio, date_s, tline
         , ( cast ( tline as int) > 6 ) as 'tv' 
        , count (distinct id) as 'cid'
FROM(SELECT id, fio, date_s
     , dbo.get_work_time(date_s, date_f, '12345', '09:00', '18:00', '0')/60 AS 'tline'
     FROM Zno_speed WHERE (date_f > @date)
    GROUP BY fio  
) tmp_table
GROUP BY id, fio, date_s, tline, ( cast ( tline as int) > 6 )
```

Comment: `but while it works it produces an error` - How exactly does it work if it produces an error...?

Comment: just add  'AS' keyword before of tmp_table . ie As tmp_table

Comment: ANSI SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"tline"`, SQL Server also supports square brackets, e.g. `[tline]`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have a real boolean data type and thus does not support boolean expressions like `cast ( tline as int) > 6`

You need to rewrite that into a case statement:

```
case when cast ( tline as int) > 6 then 1 else 0 end as tv
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE WHEN` for `( cast ( tline as int) > 6 )`

```
CASE
    WHEN ( cast ( tline as int) > 6 ) THEN 'Your Text'
    ELSE 'Your Text' END
```